# "Россия" при СССР

Tags: топонимика, история

Недавно смотрел фильм 1977 г. ("Школьный вальс"), где во время церемонии бракосочетания использовали выражение "именем Российской федерации" (по нормам того времени вроде со строчной второе слово должно писаться). В связи с этим возник вопрос, а насколько в языке времён СССР активно использовались слова "Россия" и "Российская федерация", чаще насколько знаю, пользовались аббревиатурой "РСФСР".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Российская федерация" существовала только в учебниках и в устной передаче официальных документов. В ЗАГСах, да в судах - по сути дела. Ну еще при награждении премиями и званиями. Впрочем, в последнем случае тоже чаще говорили "Россия". Вообще вспоминали наличие этой самой РСФСР (и России особенно) крайне редко, по всяким казуистическим поводам, в основном.

Я не такой старый, чтобы знать все про всю историю существования РСФСР, но за последний этап, лет пятнадцать ручаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Очень субъективный вопрос. Кому-то активно, кому-то не очень. 
Морковкин по сути прав. Если не ошибаюсь, до "Белорусского вокзала" (1977-й) с песней "А я в Россию, домой хочу" никто реально и не вспоминал, что есть такое образование. Ну еще в историко-географическом плане, как противопоставление "России" остальным частям империи: Кавказу, Малоросии, Вильненскому краю, Прибалтике (не помню, как она там называлась) Царству Польскому, Финляндии, Сибири и Туркестану. Если ничего не забыл, то все остальное и было "Россией". Какое-то смутное воспоминание о тех временах в языке еще сохранялось, "Россия" противопоставлялась остальным республикам.